Connection to Bluetooth audio devices causes internet network outages throughout all the house
I recently realized that connecting any Bluetooth headset or speaker to my Ubuntu notebook not only cuts the internet signal on this Ubuntu device, it also affects the entire network and all devices connected to it lose the internet signal.
Sometimes I can connect the Bluetooth headset and the internet continues to work for hours, but suddenly it can go down and all other devices also lose wifi connection until I turn off the WiFi on Ubuntu.
This notebook was dualboot, Windows/Ubuntu, and when used on Windows never had any problems with the Bluetooth or WiFi connection.
The problem only happens when used on Ubuntu. The only thing I know is that the problem is in the system because everything works with Windows. It's also not a problem with Bluetooth devices, because when connected to another pc or smartphones, everything works perfectly.
